# PHP - Simple add item to cart and display results

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, cart

I want to use sessions to count how many items are added to the cart. Below I have a submit button that pulls product_id from database along with title and description:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC'; 

    // Run the query:
    if($r = mysql_query($query,$dbc)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {   
            // Print out the returned results:
            print "<p><h3>{$row['title']}</h3> {$row['description']}<br />
                <form action='add_to_cart.php' method='get'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='add2cart' value='{$row['product_id']}' />
                    <input type='submit' value='Add to Cart' />
                </form>
           </p><hr />\n";
        }     
    }
```

How do I turn the below into a session to handle my form when add to cart button is submitted. This script I created just counts the cookie every time the page is called or refreshed so it is not accurate. I want to send unique product id and add item to cart using sessions so the items in cart only go up when the add to cart button is clicked.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['countItems'])){
    $Items = 0;
    setcookie('countItems', $Items); 
}
else{
    $Items = ++$_COOKIE['countItems'];  
    setcookie("countItems", $Items);
} 
define('TITLE' , 'Items in cart'); 
include('templates/header.html');
?>
<div id="main">
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$dbc = mysql_connect(DB_HOST , DB_USER , DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $dbc);


if(isset($_COOKIE['countItems'])){
    print "<p>You have $Items items in your shopping cart </p>";
    print "<p><a href='store.php'>Continue Shopping</a></p>";
}  
else{
    print "You have not added any items into your cart.";
}  

?>
```

I just need it to output what you see, it doesn't need to be a itemized or anything, just needs to count how many items are in cart and what there ids are.

Comment: Why do you need to work with cookies? You can session_start and then use $_SESSION.

Comment: I am new to php, sorry if I phrased that wrong. I don't need cookies, I am trying to rewrite to use sessions instead because cookies will not work with what I am trying to do. The above code is what I tried with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['countItems']))$_SESSION['countItems'] = 0;
else $_SESSION['countItems']++;
$Items = $_SESSION['countItems'];
```

then continue with define('TITLE' , 'Items in cart');